# In dart language. What does "transfers the memory" mean when send message between isolate?

Tags: dart

I'm new to dart language.

When I was reading the official Dart documentation, I didn't understand the following content.

> The worker isolate transfers the memory holding the result to the main isolate. It does not copy the data. The worker isolate performs a verification pass to ensure the objects are allowed to be transferred.
>
> https://dart.dev/language/concurrency

I didn't understand what does "transfers the memory" mean, what is the difference between "copy the memory"?. And if `isolate` don't copy the memory to transfer message, how `isolate` has its own memory heap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer denotes a change in ownership, from one thread to another.  It doesn't mean copy (generally) and explicitly says that in this case.